# How do I get rid of a guard stuck by the door without killing him or taking him down?

Tags: thief

I'm currently doing the last mission for Vittori, where I have to rescue someone. Playing on Master difficulty

It didn't take long for me to reach a room with a safe and a guard standing right in front of it. In order to loot the safe, I distracted the guard, but maybe I exaggerated a bit, since he freaked out, opened the door to call his friends, and has remained stuck there ever since.
When they gave up looking for me, I saved out of reflex. I regret that now...

Since I'm going for the [Moral Victory trophy](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/game/thief/trophy/80120-Moral-Victory.html), I don't want to kill or knock out that guard, but no matter what I do (running and throwing bottles around) he won't move away from that door, which also seems to be the only way to proceed in that particular level, as I haven't found any ventilation shafts so far. From time to time, I even produce enough noise for his colleagues next door to come investigate too.

In the end, I even tried running right past the guard (screw remaining undetected), but I can't run past him; he is effectively blocking my way.

It seems like the only way to make him move, is by attacking him (after he detects me, so I won't take him down), but I quickly get surrounded by 5 guards and die before I can make that one guard move enough for me to get past that door.

It doesn't look like I can restart the mission either, so what can I do?

Comment: Can you provide more details on what mission this is happening on?

Comment: @Batophobia On Vittori's last mission, where you have to rescue someone named Ysabella. But since it's not a scripted event, it could happen anywhere, I guess.

Comment: It could also just be a pathfinding issue with that specific doorway.

Comment: Have you tried going back to the last checkpoint save? They are kept separate from the manual saves and will probably go back further unless it auto-saved after you broke into the safe.